How does "regina" derive from "rex"?
How does regina derive from rex?
Related question: "Are there feminine and neuter versions of 'professor'"?

The root of rēx is rēg- (compare the genitive rēgis), which explains the first part. But where does that -īna come from?
One theory is that it comes from a Proto-Indo-European *h₃rēǵ-nih₂ "queen", also seen in Sanskrit rājñī, Gaulish rigani, Welsh rhiain, and so on. If this theory is right, Proto-Italic metathesized *rēgnīā into *rēgīnā, and regularized it into a normal a-stem. Sihler supports this one.
Another theory is that it's the same -īn- suffix that makes adjectives, with rēg-īn-a originally meaning something like "the woman intended for the king" (feminine of rēgīnus). We do see this happening with gallus "rooster" > gallīna "hen", though not with any other nouns I know of. De Vaan agrees with this theory and attributes it to Nowicki 2002.
Either way, it doesn't come from any standard way of making feminine nouns in Latin.

Note that *h₃rēǵ-nih₂ would be expected to yield Proto-Italic *rēgnī, so if the first view is right you don't just need a random metathesis but also an analogical remodelling on the "normal" a-stems first. Buck, for his part, actually already just goes with the second view (and additionally mentions gallīna as a comparandum), so I don't know why Sihler felt the need to go off on his own again.

@Cairnarvon Good point! Added a note about that.
